# How to make the select tag go before the input button tag?

Tags: html, css

i have a select and an input button tag, and in the output, the button goes first (in the left) and the select tag goes beside in the right. I want to change their position. This is my code:

```
<select class="abc">
<option value="URL">1</option>
<option value="URL">2</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="" value="GO">
```

btw the abcclass is just about the size (height and weight).

Comment: You must have some other css that's causing this. This is not normal behaviour unless styled. If you share more details, like classes that affect the `input` or `select`, your odds of a correct answer will be much greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below...

```
<table>
<tr><td>
<select class="abc">
<option value="URL">1</option>
<option value="URL">2</option>
</select></td><td>
<input type="button" onClick="" value="GO">
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: There's really no need to be rude @SeanStopnik. If you have nothing constructive to say, just a downvote will do fine to get your point across.

Comment: I am saving the person the loss of points for being downvoted. I will gladly downvote as well.

Comment: Woah, who upvoted this post? anyway, pavan please explain why you did like this?

Comment: I would use this solution in worst case if no CSS is functioning.

Comment: @ranel Although this will work for you, it is probably not the way to go. I would find the root cause of why your elements are behaving like they do, instead of falling back on using tables as an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your site has a css reset that is maybe adding a float to the button?  You can add `float: left;` to the select tag... that should fix it.

```
.abc {
    float: left;
}
```